# Handling Multiple Checkboxes with Material UI and Formik

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I have a form with a checkbox group containing 4 checkboxes within. I need to pass the value to my api on submit of button which is to be handled through Formik.

There are a few conditions on clicking a particular checkbox:

1. If Height is checked, rest all should be checked as well
2. If Breadth is checked, except for Height all should be checked
3. If Length is checked, Both Nos and Length should be checked

Nos can be checked or left unchecked

Currently I'm declaring individual states for all checkboxes and declaring individual functions for each of the conditions mentioned above.

Is there any other way to bind the values from the checkbox to Formik and pass to the api

State and Individual Functions:

```
const [nos, setNos] = useState(false);
const [length, setLength] = useState(false);
const [breadth, setBreadth] = useState(false);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(false);

const handleHeight = e => {
  setNos(!nos);
  setLength(!length);
  setBreadth(!breadth);
  setHeight(!height);
};

const handleBreadth = e => {
  setNos(!nos);
  setLength(!length);
  setBreadth(!breadth);
};

const handleLength = e => {
  setNos(!nos);
  setLength(!length);
};

const handleNos = e =>{
  setNos(!nos);
};
```

Form with Formik:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
});

return (
    <>
      <form
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        id="newJobDetails"
        name="newJobDetails"
        onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
        className={CommonClasses.formPartStyling}
        style={{
          height: SetFormSize(
            isAdd ? "Add" : textFieldDisable ? "Info" : "Edit",
            1
          ),
          marginTop: marginTop || "none",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className={CommonClasses.headingTextOfForms}
          style={{ marginLeft: "4%", marginTop: "2%" }}
        >
          Add Jobs
        </div>
        <Divider
          style={{
            marginTop: "1%",
            marginBottom: "3%",
            color: "white",
          }}
        ></Divider>
        <div
          style={{
            marginLeft: "4%",
            marginTop: "2%",
          }}
        >
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <LabelStyling>Job Name</LabelStyling>
              <TextField
                id="jobName"
                name="jobName"
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="Enter Job Name"
                value={formik.values.jobName}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                size="small"
                style={{
                  width: FORM_PART_VARS.INPUT_BOX_WIDTH,
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <LabelStyling>Stage</LabelStyling>
              <DropDown
                id="stage"
                width={FORM_PART_VARS.INPUT_BOX_WIDTH}
                value={formik.values.stage}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                error={formik.touched.stage && Boolean(formik.errors.stage)}
                helperText={formik.touched.stage && formik.errors.stage}
                mapFile={Stage}
                placeholder="Select Stage"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            marginLeft: "4%",
            marginTop: "2%",
          }}
        >
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <LabelStyling>Measurement</LabelStyling>
              <TextField
                id="measurement"
                name="measurement"
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="Enter Measurement"
                value={formik.values.measurement}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                size="small"
                style={{
                  width: FORM_PART_VARS.INPUT_BOX_WIDTH,
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <LabelStyling>Measurement Unit</LabelStyling>
              <DropDown
                id="measurement_unit"
                width={FORM_PART_VARS.INPUT_BOX_WIDTH}
                value={formik.values.measurement_unit}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                error={
                  formik.touched.measurement_unit &&
                  Boolean(formik.errors.measurement_unit)
                }
                helperText={
                  formik.touched.measurement_unit &&
                  formik.errors.measurement_unit
                }
                mapFile={MeasurementUnit}
                placeholder="Select Unit"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            marginLeft: "4%",
            marginTop: "2%",
          }}
        >
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <LabelStyling>Rate</LabelStyling>
              <TextField
                name="jobRate"
                id="jobRate"
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="Enter Rate"
                value={formik.values.jobRate}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                size="small"
                style={{
                  width: FORM_PART_VARS.INPUT_BOX_WIDTH,
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <LabelStyling>Service Rate</LabelStyling>
              <TextField
                name="serviceRate"
                id="serviceRate"
                variant="outlined"
                placeholder="Enter Service Rate"
                value={formik.values.serviceRate}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                size="small"
                style={{
                  width: FORM_PART_VARS.INPUT_BOX_WIDTH,
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            marginLeft: "4%",
            marginTop: "4%",
          }}
        >
          
            <LabelStyling>Select Measurement(s)</LabelStyling>
            
                <FormGroup row>
                <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={nos} onChange={handleNos} name="Nos" id="1"/>} label="Nos" />
                <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={length} onChange={handleLength}  name="Length" id="2"/>} label="Length" style={{marginLeft: "15px"}}/>
                <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={breadth} onChange={handleBreadth}  name="Breadth" id="3"/>} label="Breadth" style={{marginLeft: "15px"}}/>
                <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={height} onChange={handleHeight} name="Height" id="4"/>} label="Height" style={{marginLeft: "15px"}}/> 
           </FormGroup>
            
         
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            marginLeft: "4%",
            marginTop: "4%",
          }}
        >
          <LabelStyling>Select Job Type</LabelStyling>
          <FormGroup row>
            <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox name="jobType" value="Residential"/>} label="Residential"/>
            <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox name="jobType" value="Commercial"/>} label="Commercial"/>
            <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox name="jobType" value="Infrastructure"/>} label="Infrastructure"/>
          </FormGroup>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: can you provide a code sandbox with minimal reproducible example ? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Formik , it is not needed to maintain additional state to capture the form field values Formik will take care of that .

In this case , since we need to programmatically change the values of other inputs based on a change in one input we can make use of the `setFieldValue` prop provided by Formik .

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-ives-t19n3?file=/index.js)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a slight problem with the checkbox condition implementation. If I click the Height checkbox the rest of them becomes checked which is what I want. But if I click any other checkbox it becomes unchecked which should not happen. Is there any way to implement that

Comment: can you be more specific ? .

Comment: In the sandbox, you provided if I click on the last checkbox every other checkbox is also checked which is fine. But now if I click on the Breadth checkbox, the Length, Nos and the Breadth checkbox gets unchecked which should not happen.

I think the conditions are overlapping. Is there any way to overcome it and make the code such that if any of them are unchecked every other checkbox becomes unchecked too

Comment: okay so what is the expected behaviour ? should i not allow the user to uncheck breadth or if i uncheck breadth only it should be unchecked and the remaining should not be unchecked ?

Comment: Yes if the user unchecks breadth or any other checkbox for that matter everything should be unchecked

Comment: can you check the sandbox now ?

Comment: It's perfect...Thank you so much for your help...I'm pretty new to react and am still learning the basics....One of my projects required this and hence the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236439/discussion-between-shalikhshab-and-shyam).

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem and the sandbox does not implement Material UI

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple states and multiple handlers, try something like this:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
    nos: false,
    length: false,
    breadth: false,
    height: false
});

const handleCheckBox = useCallback((checkbox) => () => setState(state => {
    switch (checkbox) {
        case 'nos': return {
            ...state,
            nos: !state.nos,
        };
        case 'length': return {
            ...state,
            nos: !state.nos,
            length: !state.length,
        };
        case 'breadth': return {
            ...state,
            nos: !state.nos,
            length: !state.length,
            breadth: !state.breadth,
        };
        case 'height': return {
            ...state,
            nos: !state.nos,
            length: !state.length,
            breadth: !state.breadth,
            height: !state.height,
        };
        default: {
            console.warn('unknown checkbox', checkbox);
            return state;
        }
    }
}), []);
```

```jsx
<FormGroup row>
    <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={state.nos} onChange={handleCheckBox('nos')} name={'Nos'} id={'1'}/>} label={'Nos'}/>
    <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={state.length} onChange={handleCheckBox('length')}  name={'Length'} id={'2'}/>} label={'Length'} style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}/>
    <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={state.breadth} onChange={handleCheckBox('breadth')}  name={'Breadth'} id={'3'}/>} label={'Breadth'} style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}/>
    <FormControlLabel control={<CheckBox checked={state.height} onChange={handleCheckBox('height')} name={'Height'} id={'4'}/>} label={'Height'} style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}/> 
</FormGroup>
```